# MySQL Access a table in Memory

Tags: mysql, memory

How to access a table in Memory once it has been created?

`CREATE TABLE vendor_test ENGINE=MEMORY;  SELECT * from database.table ORDER BY ID_VENDOR ASC;`

If I run:

`SELECT * from vendor_test;`

immediately after the first two lines - it selects, but if I want to select it later it shows "ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'databse.vendor_test' doesn't exist
", yet I can see the table hanging in RAM.

Comment: What does "it does not do it" mean? Do you get an error or just an empty result?

Comment: @glglgl edited.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Always remember to c&p the error messages. Especially: did you really try to work on `databse` (which probably doesn't exist), or does the problem sit in a different spot?

Comment: @glglgl Thanks for pointing out an ambiguous problem definition. `database` is not a real name. Thing is I do not know which database must be selected to list the table stored in the MEMORY. Is there something like SHOW TABLES for Memory ones?

Comment: The memory tables are usually created in the current database, so the problem must be elsewhere. Alas, I don't have an idea what else could be the problem.

Comment: @glglgl Are these displayed along side other tables once you run SHOW TABLES on a database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166250/discussion-between-artras-kalandarisvili-and-glglgl).